# URL starting with http in MDM payload

Tags: url, https, mdm, payload

I am trying to build a configuration profile. In the the MDM payload, of the configuration profile, I enter the server url in the server field.But a red color circle appears next to the server field, when I try to enter a URL starting with "http" connection and when I enter URL starting with "https" connection the red circle disappears.

Is there any way by which I can enter a URL starting with  "http" connection and the profile gets installed correctly  or I have to stick to a "https" connection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a secure URL.

That field contains the URL for initial enrollment into the MDM system. Considering that by enrolling your device you are granting the MDM system quite a bit of access to your device (phone number, application lists, erasure, etc.), it is important to be sure that your device goes to the correct place during enrollment. Otherwise, you might open your device up to a bad actor. The `https://` helps ensure that the server your enrollment URL connects your device to is the right one.